# Height of lord shiva?

Tags: shiva, puranas

I was looking at some facebook posts and below is a pic I found in a post.

[image]

Do we have any providence about this in hindu puranas??

Or someone has just put this without any knowledge or for fun or getting likes on facebook?

Thanks

Comment: Shiva(formless Brahman) in human form is Shankara or Rudra. So question is about height of Shankara or Rudra.

Answer (score 10):

I think all this stuff about height about Shivji is misguided.
As Shiv puran has it.

> When Vishnu and Brahma couldn't decide who was greater among them, they saw a pillar. Its end couldn't be seen. So it was decided that the first one to find its end would be greater amongst the two Gods.
>   Actually God Shiva appeared as in an infinite linga (pillar). And Vishnuji tried to find the bottom of the Linga while Bramhaji tried to find its top. Both couldn't and Brahma ji lied about finding the end and was cursed. 
>   Lord Shiva tells them that it's his true form. He has no beginning and no end. He was never born nor could he die. Thus infinite pillar conveys the infinite nature of Shiva.

So, anything about the height of Lord Shiv is completely stupid.

Comment: I think he is asking about the physical height, ( or the human form height), but not the cosmic one.

Comment: I think there is no evidence about Shiv ji's height being compared to anything. Even if Shivji gave _darshan_ in normal human form, we would never know the exact height.

Comment: yes Mr.k is right.. that is what I was asking for. And there should be some reason if someone has posted/created this pic... There should something behind it...

Comment: and as your story is from ShivaPurana, but the vishnupurana and brahmanpurana has different story of lord shiva's birth... (I dont actually believe that lord shiva has ever been born), but still will wait for some other answers as well.. Thanks :)

Comment: @NishantSolanki, yes every puran has different origin story but in the end they all are one, the _Brahman_. The physical manifestation is for the ones who believe in what they see through the physical eyes.
I hope you find the right answer, Om Namah Shivaaye :-)

Comment: Mention the source or chapter-verse from Shiva Purana from where you quoted the text.

Answer (score 0):

It has two different aspects.One form of Shiva is about Adiyogi,the description is that his head matches with head of full grown horse.It can be exaggerated as 7feet. There's another dimension for word Shiva,it means that which is not.Which is not is not a thing,just empty space. So in that context there's no end and no way you can find an end to this emptiness. So the story of finding the pillar of Shiva is about finding an end to this empty space which isn't possible,so it is packed in such story.This culture is such dialectical and the all the Puranas you find are packed like that.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Consider citing sources. Visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500) and [FAQ Index for Hinduism Stack Exchange](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/478/3500).

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism. I really like the words you have used in this answer. Yes, Shiva is like a point, a point containing the whole Universe. [His every name has such deep meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Sahasranama), which is beyond any words.

Answer (score -1):

This picture is based on a true fact. This height is actually of the human form of Lord Shiva during the wedding ceremony with Parvati. I came to know about this fact from a video by Sadhguru posted on YouTube. As far as I can recall the title of the video, it should be "Shiva Parvati's Marriage" uploaded either by Sadhguru or Isha Foundation.

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Comment: Then add that video link from where you came to know about this.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE., so you are saying that Sadhguru was there to see the wedding by himself? Cite some scriptures, please. Also, do not believe in what those gurus tell you.